# Hippo trying to nstall after successful upgrade

Tags: system-installation

I successfully installed Hippo three days ago, and have been using the machine successfully without issue.

Today, I tried to boot up and it wanted to install again.

Will I lose all my stuff if I install. I don't know what to do.

I have been using Ubuntu on the machine for three years. Thus has never happened to me before, in any machine.

Comment: Did you remove the installation media?  Are you sure you actually installed the OS and that you haven't been running a live session for the past few days?

Comment: Hi Nmath I had 20.10 installed and upgraded to 21.04 through cli. No USB.

Comment: I tried to install zsh the last time I bitters it yesterday, but it didn't go all that well so I uninstalled it.

Comment: I ave gone into recovery mode and can see my account and all my files still there

Comment: I think it is definitely zsh issue. If I try to su - <user>, I get
su: failed to execute /use/bin/zsh: No such file or directory

Comment: Upgrade shouldn't be available by cli yet...  Can you please take a screenshot when "it wants to install again"?